# Is “carry out” used correctly in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage

Person 1: “Are you coming with us?”
Person 2: “I just have to CARRY OUT a few things first ,I’ll meet you there.”

What person 2 means is that:she/he has to do a few thing first.

Answer (score 1):

Not really.

"Carry out" can mean "do a specific task",  but no specific task is mentioned in the sentence, so the meaning is unclear.

You can use "carry out" with a particular task, though in this situation the most likely expression is

> I just have to do some things...  (or "I just have some things to do.")

With "carry out" you could use a specific task, for example

> I just have to carry out a check of the ground floor.